# What is the difference between metric and bucket aggregations in elastic Search?

Tags: data-request

I have started a new job where I would be using elastic search. I want to learn as much as about elasticSearch so I can hit the ground running when I start work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The aggregations framework helps provide aggregated data based on a search query. It is based on simple building blocks called aggregations, that can be composed in order to build complex summaries of the data.

Metric aggregations:

metrics aggregations are a special type of metrics aggregation which output numeric values. For example: max, min, stats, avg etc.

Bucket Aggregations:

Bucket aggregations don’t calculate metrics over fields like the metrics aggregations do, but instead, they create buckets of documents.

Furthermore, you can also combine bucket and metric aggregations to retrieve a mathematical aggregation within a bucket.

For example: Get me the average number of earthquakes occurred in North America. Where bucket is North America and the metric being used is avg.